# Absolute third central moment for standard distributions reference

Tags: r, references, expected-value, moments

I have to write an `R` function that computes the absolute third central moment (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|^3]$) in the cases that you are given the name of the distribution or the PMF/CDF. I know how to do this, but what I want is a reference for the absolute third central moment for distributions such as Bernoulli, Binomial, Geometric, Exponential, Gamma etc. (the pretty standard ones) so that I can easily check the output of my function. I don't know of any predefined `R` functions that do this either.

Comment: The best online reference is called *Wikipedia.*

Comment: Wikipedia is very handy reference, but - while it often gives an expression for moments - it usually doesn't give  third absolute  moments. If absolute moments are given at all, it's typically only the first. I can see some value in having these available, since, for example, they come up in the Berry-Esseen inequality.

Comment: @Glen_b Good point.  This is a fraught exercise because there are all sorts of numerical issues involved with the automatic integration of an arbitrary distribution function.  Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation which, if nothing else, will supply some rough reference values (and hints at an effective algorithm).  `f <- function(p = pnorm, ...) {
  mp <- integrate(\(x) 1 - p(x), 0, Inf, ...)$value;
  mm <- integrate(\(x) p(x), -Inf, 0, ...)$value;
  m <- mp + mm;
  integrate(\(x) 1 - (p(m + x^(1/3)) - p(m - x^(1/3))), 0, Inf, ...)$value
}`

Comment: @whuber I first went to Wikipedia as any good student does, but as the other user mentioned, Wikipedia doesn't really talk much about absolute moments. Thanks for your code, anyway, I know that the exercise is probably stupid, but as I said, I unfortunately *have to* do this.

Comment: @whuber I have a question: how would I adapt your approach to the discrete case? I thought that the function I was using was correct, but it unfortunately wasn't. My problem is how to compute the series involved in the formula of the expected value. In the continuous case I know the "integrate" function that you also used, but in the discrete case I am at a loss. I mean, I thought that I could somehow truncate the series, but the index in my series is not an integer or something (as I foolishly believed initially), so what could I do?

Comment: The point to my construction is that it works for *all* distributions, discrete or not, because it relies only on the distribution function. If that's not clear, here's a test function to compute the absolute moment of order $k\gt 0$ around any fixed value $a.$ With $a=0$ it will give the raw moment of order $k$ for any non-negative distribution: try it with Poisson, Binomial, Geometric, *etc.* `mu <- function(k=1, p = pnorm, a = 0, s = 100L, ...) {
  integrate(\(x) 1 - (p(a + x^(1/k),...) - p(a - x^(1/k), ...)), 0, Inf, subdivisions = s)$value
}` *E.g.*, `mu(3, ppois, lambda = 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a little analysis might help you.

The absolute moment of order $k$ (I will consider only $k\gt 0$ for convenience) around a central value $a$ for a distribution function $F$ is defined to be

$$\nu_k(F;a) = \int |x - a|^k\,\mathrm{d}F(x)$$

in the sense of Lebesgue-Stieltjes or Riemann-Stieltjes integration: this applies to continuous *and discrete* distributions.

If we let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $F,$ this is a standard formula for an expectation

$$\nu_k(F;a) = E\left[|X-a|^k\right].$$

But the distribution function of $Y = |X-a|^k,$ which has non-negative support, is readily computed from its definition for all $y\ge 0$ as

$$\begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) &= \Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(|X-a|^k\le y) = \Pr(a - y^{1/k}\le X \le a + y^{1/k})\\
&= \Pr(X\le a + y^{1/k}) - \Pr(X \lt a - y^{1/k})\\
&= F(a + y^{1/k}) - F^{-}(a - y^{1/k})
\end{aligned}$$

where I have written

$$F^{-}(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} F(x) = \Pr(X \lt x).$$

Integration by parts shows that for any random variable $Y$ whose expectation exists (even if it's infinite),

$$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty (1 - F_Y(y))\,\mathrm d y - \int_{-\infty}^0 F_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y.\tag{*}$$

When $Y$ has non-negative support, as here, the second term vanishes.

Putting these facts together gives

$$\nu_k(F;a) = E[Y] = \int_0^\infty (1 - F_Y(y))\,\mathrm d y = \int_0^\infty 1 - F(a + y^{1/k}) + F^{-}(a - y^{1/k})\,\mathrm d y.$$

Now for any $F$ you would want to consider, you may ignore up to a countable infinity of values, which means you don't have to worry about the distinction between $F$ and $F^{-}$ in the integral.  **The formula to consider implementing for any absolute moment around the mean is**

> $$\nu_k(F) = \int_0^\infty 1 - F(\mu(F) + y^{1/k}) + F(\mu(F) - y^{1/k})\,\mathrm d y$$

where, as a preliminary, you have previously computed the expectation $\mu(F) = E[X]$ by applying formula $(*)$ to $F.$

#### Remarks

**I warmly recommend implementing this more general function for arbitrary $k$** rather than focusing on $k=3,$ if only because it will permit you to test it with more readily-verified values like $k=1$ and $k=2.$

---

**You can test your implementation with simulation.**  Here are examples in `R`.  The integration is quick and dirty: it does not check the results and has only the barest provision to control the integration (*via* the number of subdivisions `s`).  The function `mu` computes ordinary or absolute moments about a central value and is used for all the integration.

```R
mu <- function(k = 1, p = pnorm, a = 0, abs.value = TRUE, s = 100L, ...) {
  sgn <- if(isTRUE(abs.value)) 1 else -1
  integrate(\(x) 1 - p(a + x^(1/k),...) + sgn * p(a - x^(1/k), ...), 
            0, Inf, subdivisions = s)$value
}
mu.p <- function(k = 1, p = pnorm, s = 100L, ...) {
  m <- mu(1, p, 0, FALSE, s, ...) # Mean
  mu(k, p, m, TRUE, s, ...)       # Absolute moment about the mean
}
```

The optional arguments `...` to `mu` and `mu.p` are any parameters you might want to pass to the distribution function `p`.  For example, here is the third absolute central moment of a Poisson$(2)$ distribution compared to a Monte-Carlo estimate:

```R
set.seed(17)
x <- rpois(1e6, 2)
print(c(Calculated = mu.p(3, ppois, lambda = 2, s = 1e4), 
        `Monte-Carlo` = mean(abs(x - mean(x))^3)))
```

> ```
>  Calculated Monte-Carlo 
>    4.706693    4.719109
> ```

The difference is attributable to random fluctuations among the million values used in the M-C estimate.

That was a Poisson calculation.  Let's try a Negative Binomial distribution (and, for fun, change $k$ from $3$ to $2$):

```R
mu.p(2, pnbinom, size = 4, prob = 1/3)
```

> ```
> Error in integrate(function(x) 1 - (p(a + x^(1/k), ...) - p(a - x^(1/k),  : 
>   maximum number of subdivisions reached
> ```

That illustrates what you might be up against with numerical integration of arbitrary CDFs.  The jumps give the integrator the willies.  Let's increase the subdivisions with the `s` argument:

```R
set.seed(17)
x <- rnbinom(1e6, size = 4, prob = 1/3)
print(c(Calculated = mu.p(2, pnbinom, size = 4, prob = 1/3, s = 1e3), 
        `Monte-Carlo` =  mean(abs(x - mean(x))^2)))
```

> ```
>  Calculated Monte-Carlo 
>    23.99989    24.11780
> ```

Again the agreement is fine.

---

**The bigger challenge lies in implementing a numerical (or symbolic) integrator that handles a wide variety of distribution functions $F.$**  Doing that well and robustly is a *huge* enterprise.  So, if you can anticipate what $F$ is likely to be, you can optimize your code for that class of distributions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I think that I understand what you did, but I am still a bit confused about the use of > integrate for the discrete case. I mean, I tried this > f <- function(x){
  if(x==1){
    0.7
  }
  else{
    0
  }
}
f <- Vectorize(f)
integrate(f, 0, Inf, subdivisions=100L)$value and it returned 0. Shouldn't it have returned 0.7? Sorry for not managing to write the code in a block, I am still new here.

Comment: I mean what I tried was to write the PMF of a Bernoulli with parameter $0.7$ and to integrate it to convince myself this works, but I think I made some mistake.

Comment: `mu(1, pbinom, abs.value = FALSE, size = 1, prob = 0.7)` performs that integration (to find the expectation) while `mu.p(3, pbinom, size=1, prob=0.7)` finds the absolute third moment around the mean.  Suggestion: plot the CDFs involved.  The integrals reduce to summing areas of a very small number of rectangles.

Comment: thanks, I understand this, but what I was trying was to write the "pbinom" part by hand (i.e. provide the distribution function directly, not through some R function) to see how this works, that's why I defined that function $f$. I see that your code produces the expected result (I had no doubt about that), but I can't see why mine doesn't when (I think) I did the same thing. Sorry if this is all very simple, but I am really inexperienced at this.

Comment: That's why I recommend plotting the graphs of the functions involved.  Algebraic integration is not easy unless you are experienced at integrating discontinuous functions.  BTW, you *shouldn't* trust code posted here.  It's almost never tested enough.  (I always do some testing, but there's just no time to do an adequate job of it.)  Assume it's not quite right and test it yourself before adapting or using it.

Comment: I see. I did test your code and it worked anyway :). I plotted the graph of my function and I think that I see what you mean: since our method of integration relies on areas of rectangles, it is natural that my function (wrongly) integrates to $0$. I think this is because of how I defined it. But how should I properly define $f$ in R so that this algebraic integration works?

Comment: I don't follow that question, because my code examples show how to do it for "properly defined" distribution functions.  Of course if you pass that code a function `p` that does not implement a valid distribution function, then you will get erroneous results.  The requirements are that it return predictable (not random) numbers; for very large negative values it returns 0; for large positive values it returns 1; and it never decreases when you increase its argument. (There are additional mathematical requirements that are irrelevant for computing.)

Comment: yes, now I am sure that the problem is in how I define my distribution function $f$. Could you help me to rewrite it correctly, please? As I said, I want it to be the PMF of a Bernoulli variable with parameter $0.7$, but I don't know how to properly define it in R, even if I know the correct mathematical formula.

Comment: If you are asking how to frame a pmf in $\mathtt R, $ this would be a different question, imo. Here whuber showed you the generic way (+1) how to implement the function that was deduced in $\mathtt R$ for a proper distribution. That was your query, I infer.

Comment: @User1865345 okay, I will post it is a separate question then.

Comment: `f <- \(x) pbinom(x, 1, 0.7)` does it.  I would guess you are reluctant to use some built-in statistical functions, but that leaves me wondering which functions you *are* willing to use.  I will suppose only the most basic ones and propose something like `H <- \(x) ifelse(x >= 0, 1, 0); f <- \(x) 0.3 * H(x) + 0.7 * H(x-1)` because this shows how to generalize it to more complicated discrete distributions.  Questions about how to code stuff are usually not considered on topic here unless they clearly require statistical explanations.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much! Yes, I basically wanted to be able to generalize this to more complicated discrete distributions. Thanks for bearing with me, I felt that this was probably not the most on topic question here, but I am really struggling in a bad statistics class that has been mostly DIY statistics without any learning materials and this was the only place I knew to ask questions.

Comment: That's what we're for.  But the labor is split up: programming questions are fielded on [SO] (which has some very stats-knowledgeable users, too) while here, although we often offer programs as parts of solutions, we focus on the stats.

Comment: If it helped, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few values to get started with since it might occasionally be handy to have some third absolute moments to refer to. I've made this answer community wiki -- anyone should feel free to edit to include more if they wish. I will try to add more when I get some time.

In each case $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the distribution in question (this way the specifics of the parameterization doesn't matter).

Normal: $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\,\sigma^3$ $\quad$  ($\approx 1.596$ for standard normal)

Exponential: $(\frac{12}{e}-2)\,\sigma^3$ $\quad$ ($\approx 2.415$ for standard exponential)

Uniform (continuous): $\frac{12^{3/2}}{32}\,\sigma^3$  $\quad$ ($\frac{1}{32}=0.03125$ for standard uniform)

(computed algebraically, checked by large simulation)

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there any efficient way to compute these third absolute moments by hand? I haven't been taught how to do this in my classes and the only thing I could come up with was computing the PMF/CDF of $|X-\mu|^3$ in the generic case.

Comment: Well, that's more work than you need to go to; [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) reduces the effort. That is, $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f(x) dx$, but particular cases can be reduced still further. I solved the normal case by using properties of the [half-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). I solved the exponential case by writing the integral in two parts (integral from $0$ to $\mu$ and $\mu$ to $\infty$ solved at $\mu=1$ and then generalized), then manipulated that ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... into an integral over the half line minus twice an integral over the first part; the first term is just a straight third central moment and the second is straightforward. The uniform reduces to evaluating a polynomial.

Comment: @justanamateur You can compute these values by integration: $m_3=\int |x-E(X)|^3 f(x)\,dx$, where $f(x)$ is the probability density. The non-centered moments can alternatively be computed by derivation of  the "characteristic function" at $x=0$; the "characteristic function" is the Fourier transform of the probability density and you can find a list on wikipedia.